# How to address properties with "." in the key name in spring 3.0 @Value tag

Tags: spring, annotations

```
@Value("#{myProperties.prop_part1_part2}")
```

works but

```
@Value("#{myProperties.prop.part1.part2}")
```

Doesn't.

How do I address a property with "." in the key ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used spring 3 yet, so my answer is a shot in the dark. Try

```
@Value("#{myProperties['prop.part1.part2']"}
```

Comment: Lovely shot in the dark. Must have left my brain at home this morning

Comment: And yes the single quotes are required